# Generic method to manage a map of collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

In the application I'm developing, I make use of several maps associating strings to collections of elements, e.g. `Map<String, List<String>>`, `Map<String, SortedSet<Object>>`. In many cases I want simple functions to add/remove elements in the collection given by a certain key, possibly removing or creating new entries in the map.

I implemented some generic methods for the effect, but the `putIntoCollection()` method is giving me some problems. My implementation, which does not rise any warning, is the following:

```
public static <K, V, C extends Collection<V>> void putIntoCollection(
        Map<K, C> map, K key, V value, Class<? extends C> collectionClass)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    C collection = map.get(key);
    if (collection == null) {
        collection = collectionClass.newInstance();
        map.put(key, collection);
    }
    collection.add(value);
}
```

`C` represents the type of the collection, which can be any type of `Collection`, and the `Class<? extends C>` parameter allows me to pass a concrete class token to instantiate new `C`'s (e.g. pass a token of `ArrayList` for a Map of `Lists`).

However, if I try to use it like this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> tags;
String key, value;
MapUtilities.putIntoCollection(map, key, value, HashSet.class);
```

I get the compile error:

```
The parameterized method <K, V, Set<V>>putIntoCollection(Map<K,Set<V>>, K, V, Class<? extends Set<V>>) of type MapUtilities is not applicable for the arguments (Map<K,Set<V>>, K, V, Class<HashSet>)
```

I understand that happens because I'm passing a `Class<HashSet>` argument while it expects a parametrized Set class. However, I don't know how (or if) can I obtain such instances of `Class`. Is there a better way to do a generic method such as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in a position to use third-party libraries?  You're basically reinventing [Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Multimap`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) -- `ListMultimap<String, String>` and `SortedSetMultimap<String, Object>` are your two examples.  A bunch of implementations are provided -- most notably, for your case, [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) and [`TreeMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html).

That said, it's generally easier to just pass an explicit factory object:

```
interface Supplier<T> { 
  T get();
}

void putIntoCollection(Map<K, Set<V>>, K, V, Supplier<Set<V>> emptySetSupplier);
```

Comment: I didn't know the library. I'm generally not fond of using general use libraries, I prefer more "compact" approaches. Nonetheless, I guess I underestimated the problem when I first started writing those methods. I'll consider using Multimaps, or use factory objects for easiness of use. For curiosity, I would still like to know if there is a way to express in "pure" Java that operation.

Comment: There's not really a good way to do it in "pure" Java, other than what I've described.  (Reflection is a _terrible_ way to do it.)  That said, you might have noticed from the other answers to this question that Guava is rather popular on SO -- basically, it's Google's utility libraries, open-sourced.  (Disclosure: I am on the Guava team.)

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem related to generic type reification... I think Guice uses a [TypeLiteral](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) to get around this problem.

But I'm going to sidestep your question. It seems like what you really want is Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). It's a collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values with a single key. It also offers utility methods such as the one you were looking for.

You can find a detailed explanation in the Guava wiki: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling a bit with generics, this is the best (working!) solution I could find:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K, V,  C extends Collection<V>> void putIntoCollection(
    Map<K, C> map, K key, V value, Class<?> collectionClass)
throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    C collection = map.get(key);
    if (collection == null) {
        collection = (C) collectionClass.newInstance();
        map.put(key, collection);
    }
    collection.add(value);

}
```

The `unchecked` warning is unavoidable, as is the `Class<?>` parameter and the `(C)` cast. The trouble you're having with this method boils down to type erasure - at runtime you can't accurately specify the generic type of the collections in the map, because this information only exists at compile time and is lost during program execution.

Now this will work without problems:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
String key="x", value="y";
putIntoCollection(map, key, value, HashSet.class);
```

Be aware, though, that this will also work without compilation errors:

```
putIntoCollection(map, key, value, Vector.class);
```

In its current form, there's no way to specify in the method that the collection values in the map (of type `Set<String>`) are of the same type as the collection values instantiated inside the method (`HashSet` in the first example, which is correct and `Vector` in the second example, which is incorrect). Again that's because of type erasure, at compile time both collection instances work fine (a `HashSet` and a `Vector`) because both implement `Collection` and contain elements of type `String`, but at runtime this line will work for the first example but will fail for the second example with a `ClassCastException`:

```
Set<String> set = map.get(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather over-engineered to me. Have you considered using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Multimaps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) instead?

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can't work because `Class<List>` is not a sub-class of `Class<Collection>`. So you won't be able to use an instance of `Class` or any other container that carries the type of interest (`? extends C`) as a generic type. You can only use `C` as a direct parameter, like a kind of prototype.

Look at `<T> T[] java.util.List.toArray(T[] a)` as an example. This method also just wants to know the type `T` of the resulting array. It can't be delivered as `Class<T>` so the method wants the client to give an instance.